# visual studio setup project caching compilation symbols

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, installation, compilation

I'm have a c# visual studio 2010 project that uses `[Conditional("DEBUG")]` above some of my logging code that I don't want used in my release build. When I build the `release` configuration in the project and step through the code, it is missed as expected.

My setup project uses the output exe file though and when I rebuilt the MSI, the debugging code was still being printed out. This occurred till I deleted the exe output from the setup project then re-added it. This is contrary to what I expected so I was wandering if other people have experienced this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#if DEBUG
...
#endif
```